# Why does $ad-bc=\pm 1$ follow?

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ , $\tau_1 \in \mathbb{H}$ .

Consider the equation $$\mathbb{Z}(a\tau_1+b)+\mathbb{Z}(c\tau_1+d)=\mathbb{Z}\tau_1+\mathbb{Z} . $$

Now I do not understand why it follows that $ad-bc=\pm 1$ .

I only come to the equation  $ad-bc=d-c$ by  comparing coefficients .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are integers $r$ and $s$ such that
$$r(a\tau+b)+s(c\tau+d)=\tau$$
and there are integers $t$ and $u$ such that
$$t(a\tau+b)+u(c\tau+d)=1.$$
Then
$$ra+sc=1,$$
$$rb+sd=0,$$
$$ta+uc=0$$
and
$$tb+ud=1.$$
Then
$$\pmatrix{r&s\\t&u}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.$$
Taking determinants,
$$(ru-st)(ad-bc)=1.$$
Both brackets are integers, so each is $\pm1$.

Comment: Thanks  a lot  , I think you made a typo $ta+uc=0 ,tb+ud=1$ but the matrix is correct .